# Writing files with fstream

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple program that accepts user input and writes it to a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name; int score; fstream scoreSheet;
    scoreSheet.open("score_sheet.txt");
    string stayOpen = "y";
    while(stayOpen == "y"){
        scoreSheet >> name >> score;
        cout << "Do you want to add another entry? (y/n) ";
        cin >> stayOpen;}
    scoreSheet.close();
    return 0;}
```

When this is run no file is created in the directory except for a gmon.out. Why isn't the file created and how do I write user input to the file?

Answer (score 1):

- For creating file and write into that file, you have to specify mode in open function.
- And also you have to scan data every time when you give Yes for write data into file.
- Below is updated code.Hope this will solve your problem.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <fstream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
   string name ; int score; fstream scoreSheet;
   scoreSheet.open("path to ur file", fstream::out | fstream::app );
   string stayOpen = "y";

    while(stayOpen == "y")
    {
       cout<<"Enter new entry for name and score"<<endl;
       cin >> name >> score;
       scoreSheet << name << score;
       cout << "Do you want to add another entry? (y/n) ";
       cin >> stayOpen;}
       scoreSheet.close();

       return 0;
     }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `>>` with `cin` or some file that exists. And the `>>` operator when used with `scoreSheet` should be a `<<` since you are trying to write **to** a stream not reading from it. Also you should consider changing `fstream` to `ofstream` since you want to write to a file

Answer (score 0):

Files are created when you open them as output, and not as input.

When you are going to read data from a file into your variables, the file should already be there (otherwise, where should the data come from?).
On the other hand, if you want to write data into your file, and therefore open it in the write mode, then the file will be created if it does not already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ofstream if you want the file stream to be written to. Also as others have commented, to write to the file, you need to get the content from somewhere else, like from console input or another file for input. Try the following code as a guide. Also you can take a look at [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/is_open/) or any decent book on this topic (e.g., C++ Primer Chapter 8)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name; int score; 
    fstream scoreSheet("score_sheet.txt", fstream::out);
    // Only proceed if file opened successfully
    if (scoreSheet) {
        string stayOpen = "y";
        while(stayOpen == "y"){
            cin >> name >> score;
            fstream << name << score << "\n";
            cout << "Do you want to add another entry? (y/n) ";
            cin >> stayOpen;
        }
        scoreSheet.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```